# Sorting hierarchical data in Javascript (Adjacency List/Flat table)

Tags: javascript, hierarchical-data

I am trying to sort the following data:

```
var data = [
    { path: '/a', order: 0 },
    { path: '/b', order: 1 },
    { path: '/a/d', order: 1 },
    { path: '/a/c', order: 0 }
];
```

Into:

```
var expected = [
    { path: '/a', order: 0 },
    { path: '/a/c', order: 0 },
    { path: '/a/d', order: 1 },
    { path: '/b', order: 1 }
];
```

I found a great post about hierarchical data:

[What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

From that question I think I am using a flat table:

> A modification of the Adjacency List that adds a Level and Rank (e.g. ordering) column to each record.

The link in that SO question is down so I can't get more information from that.

I setup a JsFiddle to assert my sort function:

http://jsfiddle.net/U76ch/

I already tried a few approaches but none of them gave the correct result.

A completely different solution would be to add the order and sort alphabetically. But since the result will end up as urls it's kinda ugly to have www.example.com/01-products/01-snowboard.

**Update**

I created a more complex JSFiddle example to show what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/YSd3d/

So I am trying to sort on path but the nodes should be sorted on order at their level. So like a file system when you sort alphabetically but the last child is sorted on order.

Comment: To your updated example: `/cars` and `/bikes` are nodes `cars` and `bikes` in the path `/`, both have to be at the beginning.

Comment: Isn't it possible to sort them the way I have in expected? I would like to have /parent, /parent/child, /parent, /parent/child depending on their order value.

Comment: Not with the sort function, because if you have two random elements, you have to say the first one is lower, higher or equal without using/knowing the other elements. But e.g. if you have the elements `/bikes/some-brand` and `/cars/bmw` the result depends on the elements `/cars` and `/bikes`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var data = [
    { path: '/a', order: 0 },
    { path: '/b', order: 1 },
    { path: '/a/d', order: 1 },
    { path: '/a/c', order: 0 }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.path === b.path) {
    return a.order < b.order ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    return a.path < b.path ? -1 : 1;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do a simple sort on it? I don't fully understand your concerns in the last paragraph.

```
var result = data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.path > b.path;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sftdq/

---

Edit. I changed your test to show order > abc. Works in [jsfiddle exmample](http://jsfiddle.net/sftdq/1/)

```
var data = [
    { path: '/a', order: 0 },
    { path: '/b', order: 1 },
    { path: '/a/a', order: 1 },
    { path: '/a/c', order: 0 }
];


var result = data.sort(function (a, b) {
    if( a.order === b.order ){
        return a.path > b.path;
    }
    else {
        return a.order > b.order;
    }
});


var expected = [
    { path: '/a', order: 0 },
    { path: '/a/c', order: 0 },
    { path: '/a/a', order: 1 },
    { path: '/b', order: 1 }
];


if (_.isEqual(result, expected)) {
    alert('Success');       
} else {
    alert('Failed');  
};
​
```

Comment: If you have /products/a-snowboard and /products/b-snowboard and I might want to have b-snowboard come before a-snowboard.

Comment: Ah, so you want to sort by `order` first, then alphabetically? Your example is sorted alphabetically despite `order`, which is why I missed it I think.